# the function to list number in a list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I have a question need your help.

> Writing a recursion function named **`list-number`** to list every number in list. For example, `(list-number '(2 a 4 b))` => `(2 4)`.

Here is my try. But it doesn't work. Could you help me figure out?

```
     (defun list-number (x)
       (cond ((numberp x) x)
             ((atom x) nil)
             (t (cons (list-number (car x)) (list-number (cdr x))))))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your function needs to distinguish three cases: 1. The list is empty. 2. The first element is a number. 3. The first element is not a number.

Comment: "But it doesn't work." - What does that mean? How did you test it?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this:

```
(list-number '(2 a))                           ; ==
(list-number '(2 . (a . ())))                  ; == 
(cons (list-number '2) (list-number '(a . ())) ; ==
(cons (list-number '2)           ; 2 is a number
      (cons (list-number 'a)     ; a is an atom
            (list-number '())))  ; () is an atom ==
(cons 2 (cons nil nil))
; ==> (2 nil)
```

Your problem is that you `cons` **before you know if it should be a part of the result or not**.

How you should do it is:

1. check if it's the empty list, then result is the empty list
2. check if the first element is a number. then you cons this number to the recursion of the rest of the list.
3. if neither two hit then the first element is not supposed to be a part of the result. Just recurse to the rest of the list since it might have numbers as well.

With this logic..

```
(list-number '(2 . (a . ())))     ; == 
(cons '2 (list-number '(a . ()))) ; ==
(cons '2 (list-number '()))       ; ==
(cons '2 '()) ; ==> (2)
```

This logic does not handle trees.

Comment: Thank very much for your answer, I will try with it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
(defvar *test '(2 a 4 b))

(defun list-number (nl)
  (cond ((numberp (car nl))
         (cons (car nl) (list-number (cdr nl))))
        ((eql nil nl)
         nil)
        (t
         (list-number (cdr nl)))))

(list-number *test)
(2 4)
```

BTW, if you want to write a tail recursive function, I recommend store statue in arguments, like:

```
(defvar *test '(2 a 4 b))
(defun list-number (head nl)
  (cond ((eql nil nl)
         head)
        ((numberp (car nl))
         (list-number (append head (list (car nl))) (cdr nl)))
        (t
         (list-number head (cdr nl)))))

(list-number '() *test)
(2 4)
```